# Problems creating an Outlook inbox rule using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I try to create an inbox rule in my Outlook Client using a powershell script but it seems that I'm unable to store the path.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mbs = $outlook.session.folders
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.outlook 
$olRuleType = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType” -as [type]
$rules = $outlook.session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
$rule = $rules.Create(“move appointments”,$olRuleType::OlRuleReceive)
$FromCondition = $rule.Conditions.From
$FromCondition.Enabled = $true
$FromCondition.Recipients.Add(“test@test.com”)
$fromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll()
$MoveRuleAction = $rule.actions.MoveToFolder
$MoveRuleAction.Folder = $mb[1].folders.item("MyTargetFolder")
$MoveRuleAction.Enabled = $true
$rules.Save()
```

when I run the script I receive this error:

```
One or more rules cannot be saved because of invalid actions or conditions.
At line:1 char:1
+ $rules.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I verified that the proper folder is accessible using $mbs[1].folders.item("MyTargetFolder") and I receive no error message, but the parent property of $MoveRuleAction is still empty. I also tried it with other folders like inbox, but this doesn't work as well.

Any suggestions how I can create this rule?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is what $mbs[1].folders.item("MyTargetFolder") looks like:

```
Application            : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                  : 2
Session                : System.__ComObject
Parent                 : System.__ComObject
DefaultItemType        : 0
DefaultMessageClass    : IPM.Note
Description            :
EntryID                : 000000007FBA7FDCC087A94D88906201B104868D010090B072A2594AD64FAA02EC7C88654D940195F69A807A0000
Folders                : System.__ComObject
Items                  : System.__ComObject
Name                   : MyTargetFolder
StoreID                : 0000000038A1BB1005E5101AA1BB08002B2A56C20000454D534D44422E444C4C00000000000000001B55FA20AA6611
                     CD9BC800AA002FC45A0C00000063687269737469616E2E6275636877616C644064652E7475762E636F6D002F6F3D54
                     55562F6F753D45786368616E67652041646D696E6973747261746976652047726F7570202846594449424F48463233
                     5350444C54292F636E3D526563697069656E74732F636E3D43687269737469616E204275636877616C6431653100E9
                     4632F44E0000000200000010000000630068007200690073007400690061006E002E00620075006300680077006100
                     6C0064004000640065002E007400750076002E0063006F006D0000000000
UnReadItemCount        : 0
UserPermissions        : System.__ComObject
WebViewOn              : False
WebViewURL             :
WebViewAllowNavigation : True
AddressBookName        :
ShowAsOutlookAB        : False
FolderPath             : \\test@test.com\MyTargetFolder
InAppFolderSyncObject  : False
CurrentView            : System.__ComObject
CustomViewsOnly        : False
Views                  : System.__ComObject
MAPIOBJECT             : System.__ComObject
FullFolderPath         : \\test@test.com\MyTargetFolder
IsSharePointFolder     : False
ShowItemCount          : 1
Store                  : System.__ComObject
PropertyAccessor       : System.__ComObject
UserDefinedProperties  : System.__ComObject
```

EDIT:I forgot to change a variable name so it wasn't working, now I solved it thanks to the code of Ranadip Dutta. This is the working code:

```
$olRuleType = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType” -as [type]
$rules = $outlook.session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
$rulefound = $false
foreach($r in $rules)
{
            if($r.name -eq "move appointments"){
                            $rulefound = $true
            }
}
if($rulefound)
{

}
else
{              
            $rule = $rules.Create(“move appointments”,$olRuleType::OlRuleReceive)
            $FromCondition = $rule.Conditions.From
            $FromCondition.Enabled = $true
            $FromCondition.Recipients.Add(“test@test.com”)
            $fromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll()
            $MoveRuleAction = $rule.actions.MoveToFolder
            $MoveRuleAction.Enabled = $true

    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MoveOrCopyRuleAction].InvokeMember(
                            "Folder",
                            [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,
                            $null,
                            $MoveRuleAction,
                            $mbs[1].folders.item("MyTargetFolder"))
            $rules.Save()
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try moving it to Junks first and check. I still believe that there is an error in your rule but it's hard to speculate by seeing it.

Comment: The script should run on many clients and other countries might have Outlook addins that could effect the Junk folder. A solution to target the proper folder is therefore preferred

Comment: user2390121: Of course it is preferred; but to isolate the issue I am asking to test with the JUNK folder.

Comment: The same issue with Junk folder as well

Comment: So that means there is some issue with the rule.

Comment: Its tough to isolate the issue by looking at it. I would like you to go through the steps followed here. Its pretty straightforward to be honest. [Have a Look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx)

Comment: The code used in the examples doesn't work, I receive the following error when I try to call the InvokeMember section: Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Non-static method requires a target."